# I need to display a graph that is constantly retracing

Tags: python, modeling, plotly, graphing

I am graphing temperature vs radius, for each tenth of a second for 1000 seconds. I am using plotly, but I cannot find the functionality to trace my trend, and then retrace it again every .1 seconds. Instead it creates a new trace and i end up with 10,000 traces - its absurd! Here is the relevant chunk of my code:

```
for i in range (0,(len(yAxis)-1)):
trace = go.Scatter(
    x = r,
    y = yAxis[i]
)
data.append(trace)

py.plot(data, filename = 'test')
```

Where yAxis is a nested list of temperature for every .1 seconds. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please fix your indentation.